# Qt Image - Somehow Image Being Saved is incorrect

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I have a bit of code that basically takes an image, edits each pixel according to the luminosity/lightness and sets the RGB to one of four values. The function, `shadeCorrection()`, is responsible for the pixel-by-pixel luminosity check. This function returns a QImage back and saves it. Upon opening this images, it is no different than the one I started with. Why is this? Here is my code:
Constructor:

```
DropSiteWindow::DropSiteWindow()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < tilePaths.count(); x++)
    {
        QImage image = QImage(tilePaths[x]);
        QPixmap newImg = QPixmap::fromImage(shadeCorrection(image));
        dropArea->setPixmap(newImg.scaledToWidth(this->width()));
        newImg.save("C:/Users/Nicholas/Desktop/Tiles/1/" + QString::number(x) + ".jpg");
    }
}
```

Function:

```
QImage DropSiteWindow::shadeCorrection(QImage image)
{
    if (image.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Image is NULL";
        return image;
    }
    QImage newImg = QPixmap(image.width(), image.height()).toImage();
    for (int w = 0; w < image.width(); w++)
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < image.height(); h++)
        {
            int lightness = QColor::fromRgb(image.pixel(w, h)).lightness();
            if (lightness >=0 && lightness <= 25)
                newImg.setPixel(w, h, qRgb(0, 0, 0));
            else if (lightness >=26 && lightness <= 128)
                newImg.setPixel(w, h, qRgb(75, 75, 75));
            else if (lightness >=129 && lightness <= 230)
                newImg.setPixel(w, h, qRgb(175, 175, 175));
            else if (lightness >=231 && lightness <= 255)
                newImg.setPixel(w, h, qRgb(255, 255, 255));
        }
    }
    return newImg;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working for me :(, can you post an example of the input image? I'm loading a JPEG image, applying the `shadeCorrection` function and saving it. It is different from original and using only 4 tones of gray. Is this the expected result? BTW, Qt 5.6.1.

Comment: @cbuchart I'm going to remove the post. I figured it out. Had something to do with using a jpg as output. I had to use a png format.

Comment: OK, anyway, I didn't have any problem exporting to JPG, may be any Qt plugins for images was missing?

Comment: @cbuchart not sure. I did have to manually add the imageformats at the exe root.

Comment: May be, I usually install them all (imageformats/*) ;)